# Invalid Signature Exception with .sav file

Tags: python, scipy, spss

New to scipy but not to python. Trying to import a .sav file to scipy so I can do some basic work on it. But, each time I try to import the file using scipy.io.readsav(), python throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-743be643d8a1>", line 1, in <module>
    dataset = io.readsav("c:/users/me/desktop/survey.sav")

  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\idl.py", line 726, in readsav
    raise Exception("Invalid SIGNATURE: %s" % signature)

Exception: Invalid SIGNATURE: b'$F'
```

Any idea what's happening? I can open the file in R and manipulate the data, but I'd like to do it in Python. Running Anaconda on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

[`scipy.io.readsav()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.readsav.html) reads [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_(programming_language)) SAVE files.  You have tagged this question `spss`, so I assume you are trying to read an SPSS file.  The format of an SPSS `.sav` file is not the same as the format of an IDL SAVE file.

Comment: That would explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look on pypi for savReaderWriter for Python code to read and write sav files.