# Read .sav file with GVAS format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Unreal Engine uses a file format called GVAS for .sav files. I am looking for a Python library that supports reading this file format. I have tried using pandas, pyreadstat, savReaderWriter, and scipy.io.readsav, but none of them were successful. Here is an example of the code I've been using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat
from scipy.io.idl import readsav
import savReaderWriter
from scipy.io import readsav

data = readsav("C:/Users/Name/Documents/Unreal Projects/Game/Saved/SaveGames/file.sav")
#Exception: Invalid SIGNATURE: b'GV'

pd.read_spss("C:/Users/Name/Documents/Unreal Projects/Game/Saved/SaveGames/file.sav")
#ReadstatError: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav("C:/Users/Name/Documents/Unreal Projects/Game/Saved/SaveGames/file.sav", apply_value_formats=True)
#ReadstatError: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features

sav_data = readsav("C:/Users/Name/Documents/Unreal Projects/Game/Saved/SaveGames/file.sav")
#Exception: Invalid SIGNATURE: b'GV'

with savReaderWriter.SavReaderNp("C:/Users/Name/Documents/Unreal Projects/Game/Saved/SaveGames/file.sav") as reader_np:
    array = reader_np.to_structured_array()
#SPSSIOError: Problem opening file b'C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Unreal Projects\\Game\\Saved\\SaveGames\\file.sav' in mode 'rb' [SPSS_INVALID_FILE]
```

Are there any Python libraries that can read a .sav file in GVAS format?

Comment: Are you able to verify that the file are correct with some other tool? Maybe it has been corrupted?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The file isn't corrupted, I can use it in Unreal. Most .sav file readers only support spss since it's significantly more common.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023695/invalid-signature-exception-with-sav-file. I think this rules out `scipy.io.readsav` as incorrect for what you are tryin to do. And maybe all of the other attempts are just assuming a very different file format than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Found this gist, that might point you in the right direction: https://gist.github.com/MartyMacGyver/ebeb8f803ef66be87c7c7d95d000ab42